# Smooth out parallax in React component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a React component with a simple parallax that changes the top and opacity values. The problem is the scroll animation is kind of jerky. Is there any way I can smooth out the transitions? I was using `requestAnimationFrame()` in vanilla JS, but I don't think I can use it in the React component as the rendering cycle is different.

Additionally, how can I stop changing the state once the element is out of the viewport?

Here is my implementation:

```js
const Parallax = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {
    return {
      top: 0,
      opacity: 1
    };
  },

  parallax: function(event) {
    const scrollTop = window.pageYOffset;
    const elementHeight = this.splash.clientHeight;

    this.setState({ top: scrollTop * .7 + 'px' });
    this.setState({ opacity: (elementHeight - scrollTop) / elementHeight });
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.parallax);
  },

  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.parallax);
  },

  render: function() {
    const splashStyle = { 
      transform: 'translateY(' + this.state.top +')',
      opacity: this.state.opacity
    };

    return (
      <div className="splash" 
        ref={ domElement => { this.splash = domElement; }}>

        <div className="splash__wrapper " style={ splashStyle }>
            <p>LONG CONTENT</p>
        </div>

      </div>
    );
  }

});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Parallax />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```css
.splash {
      position: relative;
      width: 100vw;
      max-width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
      min-height: 500px;
      background: url(https://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png) no-repeat 10% 60%;
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
    }
    
    .splash__wrapper {
      position: absolute;
      color: #fff;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
      transition: 0s transform;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

**Update:**

The Splash component is at the top of the page, so I was able to limit the state changes to when the element is in view with the following. No luck on improving the scroll performance.

```
if (scrollTop < elementHeight) {
  this.setState({ top: scrollTop * .7 + 'px' });
  this.setState({ opacity: (elementHeight - scrollTop) / elementHeight });
}
```

Comment: Did you test your implementation with the production build of react? I created a fiddle that seems to run smoothly: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/82639/ . Also do not use `getElementsByClassName()`. Instead you should [use a ref](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#when-to-use-refs) to reference your DOM element.

Comment: @trixn Thanks for the ref tip. I've updated my example.

Comment: react-scroll-parallax has [several tactics to keep parallax smooth](https://github.com/jscottsmith/react-scroll-parallax#optimizations-to-reduce-jank) I have a similar problem to you so I'm going to try these out.

Answer (score 0):

A user scrolling the page triggers a lot of scroll events. 
You don't want to react to every scroll event but group them, for instance every 1000 milliseconds.

This is called throttle. The [lodash library](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#throttle) has a nice throttle method, but others exist.

With the lodash library included your eventlistener would look like this ...

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', _.throttle(this.parallax, 1000));
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this didn't work for me - even with a time interval of 10 milliseconds.